# Is Chrome (not chromium) allowed to be installed in Ubuntu MATE - Raspberry pi 3B?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Raspberry - 3 B and trying to install chrome (not chromiun) in Ubuntu Mate.

For my laptop ubuntu 16.04 LTS version I use the follow:

```
  wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
  sh -c 'echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
  apt-get update
  apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

But when I try the same for Ubuntu Mate  I have an error.
Is it related to the chrome amd64 architecture ? So is chrome allowed or not to install in raspberry pi -3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chromium is the fully [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) version of Chrome.  Since the complete source code is available, anyone can try and compile it, so pre-compiled versions for a variety of platforms including the Pi are available.

Chrome proper includes proprietary bits, so the only binaries available are from Google.  Their download page is a bit high on glitz, low on information, but it is fairly implicit there is no ARM version viable on any model of Pi.